# Add script tag to Bigcommerce shop

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am building plugin for Bigcommerce shops and I found out, that there is no way of adding script tags to shops. This funcionality is present in Shopify, thats why I thought it should be also available in your API. Maybe there is some kind of workaround? 
(https://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/scripttag)

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to dynamically add tags to BigCommerce themes, but we have upcoming releases that should allow this. In the meantime, you can add a script tag manually to the web analytics box, the theme files, or through the footer scripts box in the control panel.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to build an app for commerce sites or are you building shops for your clients?

If you are building shops for your clients you can go to the shop dashboard, edit themes, and update the layout.liquid file.

If you are building an app for shops you need to use the post script tags API that you referenced.

What language are you programming in?

https://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/scripttag#create

Comment: I need to add script tag to Bigcommerce, not Shopify